# Preparing / Rendering Image for Image Classification with MNIST FASHION in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, rendering, image-classification

I know this question has previously been asked, but I still face some problems.

Having set up the Neuronal Network and trained the model, I now would like classificate images from my Desktop. For this reason the images gotta prepared before the supervised learning…

How can I transform a normal picture into the format (1, 28, 28) ?

I tried doing so by

```
Img = imageio.imread(f‘path/pic.png‘)
Image = numpy.expand(Img, 0)
Print(Image.shape) RETURNS (1, 28, 28, 3) and NOT (1, 28, 28)
```

Any Ideas, Inspirations, …
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `imageio` library, you can instead use OpenCV, which is the `cv2` library (needs to be installed first).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

Img = cv2.imread('path/pic.png', 0)  # Need to pass in the zero as a flag to be read in gray-scale
Image = np.expand_dims(Img, 0)
print(Image.shape)

> (1, m, n)
```

Comment: Awesome that’s a simple and quick solution, Thx Omar ;)